# How should I define or reinitialize this variable?

Tags: jquery, closures

I have something like this:

```js
var menu = (function() {
  var itemContainer = $('#item-container');
  var items = $('.item');

  return {
    countItems: function() {
      //do something with items object.  This does not work.
      console.log('items.length: ' + items.length)
    },
    manipulateItemContainer: function() {
      //do something with itemContainer object. This works fine.
    },
    populate: function() {
      //dynamically create elements with .item class
      var item1 = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'item'
      }).appendTo(itemContainer);
      var item2 = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'item'
      }).appendTo(itemContainer);
      var item3 = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'item'
      }).appendTo(itemContainer);
    },
    addItem: function() {
      var item = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'item'
      }).appendTo(itemContainer);
    }
  }

})();

menu.populate();
menu.countItems();
menu.addItem();
menu.countItems();
```

```css
.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item-container">
</div>
```

In this scenario, `items` is empty.  How should I reconfigure this to address the issue?  Create an `init()` function and run it at the end of `.populate()`?  Other options?  Or am I missing something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of items available is dynamic, perhaps using retrieving them with a function call would work better:

```
var menu = function() {
  var itemContainer = $('#item-container');

  function getItems() {
      return $('.item');
  }

  return {
    manipulateItems: function() {
      //do something with items object.  This does not work.
      // check if there are any items first
      if (getItems()) {
        // work with items
      }
    },
    manipulateItemContainer: function() {
      //do something with itemContainer object. This works fine.
    },
    populate: function() {
      //dynamically create elements with .item class
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This works, but what if I add or remove items outside of the populate function?  I updated the question to add an `.addItem()` method.

Comment: Gotcha. Try using a little private function instead (I updated my answer). This way you'll get the latest available each time.